# Server Error in Application

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, service-applications

My SharePoint 2013 site stopped working today and cannot find the source of the issue. I wonder if anybody has the expertise to work out what the error below means or how I can go about trouble-shooting the issue.

The windows server was installing updates at the time but this may just be a coincidence and can not find any updates that may have caused a problem. Tried restarting services/iis/application pools but no luck. Central admin also does not load

Thanks

> Server Error in '/' Application
>
> Derived method 'RequiresWebPartClientScript' in type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermProperty' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' cannot reduce access
>
> [TypeLoadException: Derived method 'RequiresWebPartClientScript' in
>   type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TermProperty' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' cannot reduce access.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.TaxonomyNavigationContext.EnsureCallbackInitialized()
>   +0
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +256    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,
>   Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +14297981
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +198    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +28
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +66
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +309
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext)
>   +1227    System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +139
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +322
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +384
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +397
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +646
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +779

Comment: Is it production or stagging? what CU level you are?

Comment: You sure it is windows update only, becuase Now a days SharePoint Updates also part of WIndows updates. http://msprojectnow.com/Blog/tabid/142/entryid/813/Derived-method-RequiresWebPartClientScript-error-after-installing-Project-Server-2013-with-SP1.aspx

Comment: Hi unfortunately it is a production server. I think I am on version 14.0.0 with no CU

Comment: Looks like you need the latest SP /CU, inorder to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Run the Configuration Wizard.

This should be the last step after updates have been installed.

(This should be done after hours as this does require IIS resets)

[Install a software update (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806338(v=office.15).aspx)

Should also help get you back into Central Admin

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "/_admin/FarmServer.aspx" page from the central administration and if we have multi severs farm – check the upgrade status for each server in the farm like the below screen:

[image: SharePoint Upgrade block status]

**Notes:**

- In this page for all servers in the farm should be upgrade is not required.
- If the upgrade is required, please upgrade them one by one.
- If it showed upgrade blocked, we must upgrade all servers in the farm, otherwise, none of the sites will gent opened.
- Before running the Wizard, make sure to take all necessary backups.

For more details - please refer the below article:

[SharePoint Server Error:](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-troubleshooting/server-error-http-go-microsoft-com-fwlinklinkid177673-in-sharepoint-sites/)